# What claim did Rita have on the Power Coins?

Tags: power-rangers

When the history of the Power Coins are revealed it is said that Zordon and Rita flipped for the coins and Zordon won 5 of the coins and Rita won the 6th. This would imply that Rita had some claim on the Power Coins and the Zords (since she also got the Dragonzord) even though the power coins belong to the Rangers who exist to fight against evil and Zordon is the one who made the Zords. The only thing I can think of is that Rita was at one point an ally and perhaps a ranger herself. Surely this can't be the case.

So what was her claim?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Power Rangers wiki](http://powerrangers.wikia.com/wiki/Power_Coins#Dinosaur_Power_Coins), the six Power Coins were hidden in the [Temple of Power](http://powerrangers.wikia.com/wiki/Temple_of_Power) in the Desert of Despair located on Rutabaga 6, in the Rutabaga system.

Zordon and Alpha Four located five of the coins near there, following a map.  There's no indication that they knew of the sixth coin at that point.

Later, Rita located the temple and captured the sixth coin while doing battle against Rooten-Toomen, who ruled the planet.

These details are all pulled from a comic entitled [Going Green](http://powerrangers.wikia.com/wiki/Going_Green), published by Papercutz in 2014.

Comment: The only problem with this is that Zedd was the Green Ranger in the original 5 rangers and it was the Black Power Coin that was missing, but that's not your fault that there is an error, especially in the Ninja coin part.

Comment: @Durakken: Where do you get this information?  In the TV show of MMPR, Zedd was never known to be any type of power ranger, and Tommy was always the initial green ranger.  And what Ninja Coin part?  The coins that Zordon and Rita found were the original Dinosaur coins, though they were made by the same person who eventually made the Ninja coins.

Comment: The Megaforce season revealed that the original 5 rangers were Zordon (Red) Dulcea (pink) Gosei (blue) Master Vile (Yellow) and Lord Zedd (Green). The story you are relaying is from the episodes surrounding them getting their Ninjetti Powers & Coins from Ninjor. Ninjetti Story stuff is odd due to The Movie and the semicannonization of it along with the errors in surrounding those coins that cropped up as the the series went on. You can argue that cuz of the huge timespan Zordon made other Powers (as he did)  though doesnt seem the case with the dino coins & returns us to the original problem.

Comment: Okay....where did all this information come from? this is the first I'm hearing of any of it

Answer (score -1):

OK, @durakken, you don't use fanfic to argue plot points. You are entirely wrong on absolutely everything you stated. Op, she had no claim on the zords or coins save for the green coin and dragonzord. The coin toss was not to win the power coins but to determine the end of the war. After Zordon won, he sealed Rita and her henchmen into the dumpster but Rita had a trick up her sleeve and sealed zordon into a time warp at the same time.

Comment: You start with an irrelevant comment, move onto the answer but the deter away from it. Can you [edit] it to make sure you're really addressing the question